# 1999 USAMO submission by Titu Andreescu Problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The task is the following:

2. [USAMO 1999 submission, Titu Andreescu] Let $n$ be an odd integer greater than 1 . Find the number of permutations $p$ of the set $\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ for which
   $$
   |p(1)-1|+|p(2)-2|+\cdots+|p(n)-n|=\frac{n^{2}-1}{2}
   $$
   Solution I don't understand:

We have
$$
\begin{array}{l}
|p(1)-1|+|p(2)-2|+\cdots+|p(n)-n| \\
\quad=\pm 1 \pm 1 \pm 2 \pm 2 \pm \cdots \pm n \pm n
\end{array}
$$
The maximum of $|p(1)-1|+|p(2)-2|+\cdots+|p(n)-n|$ is
$$
\begin{array}{l}
2\left(-1-2-\cdots-\frac{n-1}{2}\right)-\frac{n+1}{2}+\frac{n+1}{2} \\
\quad+2\left(\frac{n+3}{2}+\cdots+n\right)
\end{array}
$$
$$
=-\left(1+\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \frac{n-1}{2}+\left(\frac{n+3}{2}+n\right) \frac{n-1}{2}=\frac{n^{2}-1}{2}
$$
Let $p\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)=k$. We must have
$$
\left\{p(1), p(2), \ldots, p\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\right\}=\left\{\frac{n+3}{2}, \frac{n+5}{2}, \ldots, n\right\}
$$

and
$$
\left\{p\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right), p\left(\frac{n+5}{2}\right), \ldots, p(n)\right\}=\left\{1,2, \ldots, \frac{n+1}{2}\right\}-\{k\}
$$
if $k \leq \frac{n-1}{2}$, or
$$
\left\{p(1), p(2), \ldots, p\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)\right\}=\left\{\frac{n+1}{2}, \frac{n+3}{2}, \ldots, n\right\}-\{k\}
$$
and
$$
\left\{p\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right), p\left(\frac{n+5}{2}\right) \ldots, p(n)\right\}=\left\{1,2, \ldots, \frac{n-1}{2}\right\}
$$
if $k \geq \frac{n+1}{2} .$ There are
$$
\frac{n-1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) !\right]^{2}+\frac{n+1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) !\right]^{2}=n\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) !\right]^{2}
$$
such permutations.

Comment: Please don't use pictures. Use MathJax. Here is a 
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: To scan formulae, you can also use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathpix.snip).

Comment: Which specific part of the solution do you first not understand? (This seems pretty straightforward for a writeup, and it's how I would have approached it, so you need to specify your concerns and elaborate on why it seems confusing to you. We're not all mind-readers.)

Comment: @CalvinLin oops, turns out I forgot to say which part I don't understand when I constructed the post the 2nd time. I don't understand the part after obtaining the maximum.

Comment: @Invisible thanks

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'll look into it

Comment: Hint: What does the maximum of the expression is $\frac{n^2 - 1 } { 2}$ imply about the values of $p(i)$? EG Can $ p(1) = 1$? Can $p(1) = 2$? Can $p(2) = 1$? $quad$ Hint: Condition on $p(\frac{n+1} {2} ) \leq \frac{n-1}{2} $, what can we say about the values of $ \{ p(1), p(2), \ldots p(\frac{n-1}{2} )$? Why?

Comment: Marko, nema na čemu. (: